# Update textview every x seconds to show notification in background

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
public void LoadCurrentTime(long time_last) {
    long millis_now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time_till = millis_now - time_last;
    String showTime;
    int showHours, showMin, showSec;
    if (time_till > 604800000) {
        showTime = getString(R.string.long_ago);
    } else {
        //long longHours = (time_till / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        //long longMin = (time_till / 1000 / 60 % 60);
        //long longSec = (time_till / 1000 % 60);
        //showHours = (int) longHours;
        //showMin = (int) longMin;
        //showSec = (int) longSec;
        //showTime = String.format("%02d", showHours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", showMin) + ":" + String.format("%02d", showSec);
        // v1.0^
        long longsec = (time_till / 1000) % 60;
        long longmin = (time_till / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long longhours = (time_till / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        showHours = (int) longhours;
        showMin = (int) longmin;
        showSec = (int) longsec;
        showTime = String.format("%02d", showHours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", showMin) + ":" + String.format("%02d", showSec);

    }
    TextView lastTime = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
```

I want to update a `TextView` content every second and show a notification, but the `TextView` update and the notification show only when open the app, so
How can I update the `TextView` and show notification every one second in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user Timer and TimerTask to for recurring tasks. Don't forget to call timer.cancel() at end of the program.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //Call your method
          LoadCurrentTime()
        }
    },0, 2000);
```